# Unable to run cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I downloaded cassandra binary from apache site, version 3.11.5. OS is Windows 10.
But running command 'cassandra' in bin directory gives error:

> ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:1] 2020-01-28 14:04:34,589 DefaultFSErrorHandler.java:92 - Exiting forcefully due to file system exception on startup, disk failure policy "stop"
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: Invalid folder descriptor trying to create log replica C:\work\softwares\cassandra\apache\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogReplica.create(LogReplica.java:58) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogReplicaSet.maybeCreateReplica(LogReplicaSet.java:86) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogFile.makeRecord(LogFile.java:311) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogFile.add(LogFile.java:283) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogTransaction.trackNew(LogTransaction.java:139) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.5.jar:3.11.5]

Do I need to do something extra?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are hitting https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15426.

For now, try running 3.11.4 instead.